# Fixed Background-attachment with image width relative to container width

Tags: html, css, background-image

This is my code:

```
body {
max-width: 1400px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

section {
    background-image: url(image.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 575px;
}
```

What ends up happening is the background image shown is only 1176px wide, not 1400 px wide.  When I set to background-size:cover, then the image is 1400px wide which is what I want, however the image stretches the full width of the screen but only 1400px is visible.  Parts of the image are cut off.  Basically I need the image to be 1400px wide but to also scale the image so it's not cutting it off on the sides.

For the script to work properly with stellar.js, I need to have background-attachment:fixed in there.

I've added a sample - http://jsfiddle.net/9a7wegkh/ (max-width set to 300px because of jsfiddle window size, same idea though)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701340/firefox-background-image-horizontal-centering-oddity?rq=1 check this answer.

Comment: @JPrakash I read that...tried adding max-width to html instead of body, but it didn't have any impact

Comment: try `max-width : 100%;` instead of `max-width : 1400px;`